# Hide div based on value of select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a select dropdown with a list of servers with varying types of encryption.

Currently I am able to display the encryption type of the currently selected option in a label (id="type") but I also want to hide a div (#secure) if encryption = none.

I've tried adding   `if x = none; $("#secure").hide()`  to the myFunction script but that stops the dropdown populating, I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

So basically what I'm looking to achieve is if x = none, hide div. Thanks in advance.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("encryption").value;
  document.getElementById("type").innerHTML = "Encryption type: " + x;
}
```

```html
<select class="browser-default" id="servers" name="servers" onchange="myFunction()" </select>
<p id="type"></p>

<div class="secure"> This server is secure </div>
```

Comment: where is that part of the code? the `if x ...` ? plus you should use `===` not `=`

Comment: `if (x == "none") $(".secure").hide() else $(".secure").show()`  or, with a less obvious "if": `$(".secure").toggle(x=="none")`

Comment: post your all relevant code

Answer (score 1):

`=` is an assignment operator. You want to use `==` for comparison:

```
if (x == 'none') {
    $("#secure").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the question is if none is string or what?

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("encryption").value;
  document.getElementById("type").innerHTML = "Encryption type: " + x;
  if(x === "none") <--- pay attention here if none is really a string
  { 
     document.getElementById("secure").style.display = "none"; <-- this actually hides the element.
  }
}
```